# Python Error with processing multiple files

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to read multiple files one by one from subfolders, do some processing and output. Below is my code:

```
import os
rootdir = 'dir'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for fname in files:

        print os.path.join(subdir, fname)

        f = open(fname, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()

        f = open(fname, 'w')
        for line in lines:
            f['X1'] = f['X1'].astype(str)
```

But I am having the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno2] No such file or directory : 'test.txt'
```

Comment: You print the result of `os.path.join`, but you then open `fname`, not the joined subdir + fname. Is that correct?

Comment: Please format your question and add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are doing this:

```
os.path.join(subdir, fname)
```

But you are not assigning it to a variable, so when you do this:

```
f=open(fname,'r')
```

You are still only using the filename.

You should do this:

```
file_path = os.path.join(subdir, fname)
```

So now you actually have the file path. Then this:

```
f=open(file_path,'r')
```